# php pages in mysql link without id

Tags: php

How I add pages for my website without create files for any page I want. To make understand let's say I need a details information page to read from mysql the rest of informaton of a specific ID BUT! in link i don't want to be with id

> (site.com/details-product-idnumber)

i want to be only

> (site.com/details-product-nameofproduct)

I know basicly this need to be rewrite from .htaccess but what I need to know about this function/system.

Another example is wordpress blog platform, when you add a post, in link it only the title of the ID post from mysql, what php code i need to use or what's the name of this function. Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials - come back with specific problems

Comment: As long as you can *identify* the data to return from the URL then that works as an *ID*.  There's no rule that IDs need to be numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you can use a `unique_name (in your application a unique name for a product)`.. in your `database table`.. and just pass that `unique_name` in the link..

like..

```
site.com/details-product-unique_name
```

and your `sql query should be like`..

```
select * from product where unique_name = '$_GET["your_get_field"]';
```

let me know if you want any further guidance...

Comment: Please rewrite this so as to not encourage SQL injection.

Comment: @PatrickQ I could provide that also.. but I dont think this question is related to `prevention from sql injections`.. otherwise I have provided `data binding` using `mysqli or pdo`... I dont want the user to get **distracted** or **confused**.. thanks btw..